# Max function using sql in sap Hana

Tags: sql, powerbi, hana

I’m trying to remove duplicates from my table using a SQL query in SAP Hana I have written my statement

```
Select customers, agent, factory, max(total sales)
From table (table name)
Where total sales is not null
Group by customers, agent, factory
```

I get results but the problem is that the duplicates were still in the table the table is calculating multiples rows, what can I do?

Comment: Hana != SQL Server

Comment: This query should return unique row for any customers, agent and factory. Please check whether there are duplicate rows for same customers, agent and factory or their values are different.

Comment: To check values in what columns are repeating for the combination of customers, agent and factory , you could try this query - `select customers, agent, factory,* from <table> where total sales is not null
group by customers, agent, factory; ` Once you get what columns could have repeating values, you can add them as well in the select and group by clause.

Comment: Please clarify your question. For instance provide an example with input data and expected result. NB: you use `SELECT` to **read** the rows of the table, but you say "*the problem is that the duplicates were still in the table*" like you'd wish to **delete** duplicate rows from the table (i.e. by using `DELETE` instead of `SELECT`).